# Symfony 4.3: return $this->json($entity) sometimes returns empty result

Tags: symfony4

I have started migrating from Symfony 3.4 to 4.3 in the last couple of days. My Controller functions almost exclusive return JSON results or rendered views.

As per the Symfony 4.3 documentation, I am using `return $this->json($entity);` on `getEntity()` functions where I want to return the full data on a certain Entity. I find that this works, and then doesn't work, where the returned result either contains my entire entity in JSON format, or just {}.

`print_r($entity);` just before the return shows that the entity is not empty. I am unable to figure out why the response is empty, and why it sometimes works and other times not. This is not "random" as in works once or twice and then doesn't work. It either works consecutively for a long time or doesn't.

Comment: Referenced Documentation: https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller.html#returning-json-response

Comment: This seems to work when symfony/serializer is installed, but not without it. According to the documentation it should work irrespective of whether serializer is installed.

Answer (score 1):

Try using JSONRESPONSE:

```
return new JsonResponse($entity,200);
```

Comment: Response 200 is a default value.

Comment: Still empty result